# How do i connect to a computer which is on LAN and connected to internet via router?

Tags: networking, web-applications, localhost, lan

I am developing a web app. This app will be deployed on a web after completion. This app generates a data in .xml file which needs to be imported by a computer which is on LAN. It has internet connection via router. How do i connect to that computer?

For example i have a computer with LAN ip 192.168.1.3. As implied it is lan ip and is not available to outside world. This computer needs to import .xml file from www.demowebapp.com. How this can be possible?

Answer (score 0):

use port forward (if your router support it )

Comment: i checked this. https://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for

Now are the ip of my router is static? or they change when i restart my router? I am using cable internet.